# Concatenar duas colunas com Excel Vba em seis abas diferentes

Tags: excel-vba

Preciso Concatenar com VBA os textos contidos em duas colunas em planilha Excel, juntando-os em uma outra coluna, porém efetuando este procedimento para seis abas.

Os dados das colunas B e H precisam ser concatenados com um espaço entre eles na coluna A.
Adaptando códigos que encontrei consegui efetuar o procedimento para apenas uma aba, porém como não tenho o conhecimento necessário de estruturas de repetição, não estou conseguindo efetuar nas demais.
Vale ressaltar que a planilha contém outras abas além das seis, e nestas outras não pretendo efetuar a concatenação, até porque tem layout diferente das demais, o que impede de efetuar o procedimento por pasta de trabalho.

As abas onde desejo a concatenação estão denominadas assim:

```
SEM_0_EQUIP, SEM_1_EQUIP, SEM_2_EQUIP, SEM_0_LOCAIS, SEM_1_LOCAIS, SEM_2_LOCAIS
```

O código já existente e adaptado ficou assim:

```
Sub Concatena_dados_de_duas_colunas()

Dim vaColuna2 As Variant, vaColuna8 As Variant, vaDados() As Variant 'variavel para as colunas 2, 8 e dados
Dim wsPlan As Worksheet
Dim rnColuna2 As Range, rnColuna8 As Range, rnDados As Range 'variavel para as colunas 2 e 8
Dim iNumero As Long

Set wsPlan = Worksheets("SEM_0_EQUIP") 'A variavel é igual a planilha desejada
Set rnColuna2 = wsPlan.Range("B3", Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)) 'setada a coluna 2 com o range possivel
Set rnColuna8 = wsPlan.Range("H3", Range("H1048576").End(xlUp)) 'setada a coluna 8 com o range possivel

vaColuna2 = rnColuna2.Value
vaColuna8 = rnColuna8.Value

ReDim vaDados(1 To UBound(vaColuna2))

For iNumero = 1 To UBound(vaColuna2)
vaDados(iNumero) = vaColuna2(iNumero, 1) & " " & vaColuna8(iNumero, 1)
Next iNumero

Set rnDados = wsPlan.Range("A3", Range("A" & UBound(vaColuna2) + 2)) 'o mais dois no final é para fazer com que os dados comecem na linha 3
rnDados.Value = Application.Transpose(vaDados)

vaColuna2 = rnColuna2.Value
vaColuna8 = rnColuna8.Value

ReDim vaDados(1 To UBound(vaColuna2))

For iNumero = 1 To UBound(vaColuna2)
vaDados(iNumero) = vaColuna2(iNumero, 1) & " " & vaColuna8(iNumero, 1)
Next iNumero

Set rnDados = wsPlan.Range("A3", Range("A" & UBound(vaColuna2) + 2)) 'o mais dois no final é para fazer com que os dados comecem na linha 3
rnDados.Value = Application.Transpose(vaDados)

End Sub
```

Acredito até que há possibilidade de melhorar este código.

Answer (score 0):

Como vai?

Como você precisa preencher em poucas abas, a solução pode ser resolvida com uma estrutura de repetição "For...each" e uma cláusula "If".

Basicamente, o código abaixo percorre cada aba da planilha cujo nome estiver estipulado na cláusula "If" e, em seguida, preenche a coluna A com os valore concatenados das colunas B e H de cada planilha, até a última linha preenchida na coluna B:

```
Private Sub btConcatenacao_Click()

Dim Sheet           As Worksheet
Dim A               As Integer
Dim UltCel          As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Apaga a coluna A das planilhas
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
    If Sheet.Name = "SEM_0_EQUIP" Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_1_EQUIP" Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_2_EQUIP" Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_0_LOCAIS" _
       Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_1_LOCAIS" Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_2_LOCAIS" Then
    
        Sheet.Range("A:A").EntireColumn.ClearContents
            
    End If

Next Sheet

'Realiza a rotina de concatenação nas abas desejadas
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
    If Sheet.Name = "SEM_0_EQUIP" Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_1_EQUIP" Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_2_EQUIP" Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_0_LOCAIS" _
       Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_1_LOCAIS" Or Sheet.Name = "SEM_2_LOCAIS" Then
    
        A = 1
        Set UltCel = Sheet.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)
            
        Do While A <= UltCel.Row
        
            Sheet.Range("A" & A).Value = Sheet.Range("B" & A).Value & " " & Sheet.Range("H" & A).Value
        
            A = A + 1
        
        Loop
            
    End If

Next Sheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

A planilha que eu usei foi essa: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20210410WYCuKYdG

Espero que ajude!